# Min function ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, min

I wanted to use `Min` function from ArcPy. Here there is a link to documentation (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/image-analyst/min.htm).

I wrote that code:

```
from arcpy.ia 
import Min 
rc = RasterCollection([raster1, raster1])
RzekiIJezioraEucDistance = Min(rc, extent_type = "UnionOf", cellsize_type = "MinOf", ignore_nodata = True,  process_as_multiband= True) 
RzekiIJezioraEucDistance.save(r"RzekiIJezioraEucDistance.tif")
```

And I got that error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Min' from 'arcpy.ia' (C:\Program
> Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\ia_*init*_.py)

I don't know how to fix it. I think I've done everything just like it is in documentation.

Comment: Have you tried `from arcpy.ia import *` like the sample in the documentation?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Pro are you using?